# Can $z + \frac{1}{z}$ or $z + \frac{2}{z}$ be considered as quadratic forms?

Tags: quadratic-forms

Can $$z + \frac{1}{z}$$ or $$z + \frac{2}{z}$$ be considered as [quadratic forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form)?

Comment: Why is there a close vote on this question?  And could the downvoter kindly explain his/her vote?  I think the question is pretty straightforward, and has been answered to my satisfaction by [Kenny Lau](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/328173).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=\sqrt z$ and $y=\dfrac1{\sqrt z}$.

Then, $z+\dfrac1z=1x^2+0xy+1y^2$ and $z+\dfrac2z=1x^2+0xy+2y^2$.

However, this only works when $z\ge0$.

Comment: So $x+y$ is also a quadratic form because I can write $x' = \sqrt x$ and $y' = \sqrt y$? Your answer makes me wonder what is a quadratic form now.

Comment: @JohnMa the confusion all goes away when you specify that a function is a quadratic form **of $x$ and $y$**.

Comment: So the answer to the question given by the OP should be yes or no, depending on which variables you choose?