# Is $X + \frac{2}{X}$ a rational quadratic form, where $X \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: quadratic-forms, representations-by-quadratic-forms

First of all, I apologize for the rather silly question.  This came up while I was scouring the Internet on a mathematical terminology appropriate for a concept that I need for a paper which I am currently writing.

So here it is:

> Is $X + \frac{2}{X}$ a rational quadratic form, where $X \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$?

Or to put in another way:

> Can the rational function $X + \frac{2}{X}$ be represented by a quadratic form, where $X \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$?

I know that I can just check Cassels' *Rational Quadratic Forms*, unfortunately the nearest university library is a bit far from my place of residence (not to mention being closed during the holidays).

Comment: @flawr:  I would go with the definition in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_form), although honestly, I was not able to spot an actual definition for *rational quadratic form* but only for *quadratic form* per se.

Comment: My apologies!  I meant to say $X \in \mathbb{Q} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$.  Editing my question now to reflect this change.

Comment: I just started a bounty on this question.  Basically, I want to know whether this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2422418/28816) still applies to the present scenario, in the context of *rational quadratic forms*.

Answer (score 1):

Cassels will tell you that a quadratic form $Q(x)$ on $\mathbb{F}^n$ is just 
a function such that

1) $Q(\lambda x) = \lambda^2 Q(x)$,

2) $B(x,y):= (Q(x+y) -Q(x) -Q(y) )/2$ is bilinear.

Given any degree two polynomial in one variable, $p(x)$, we can always turn it into a quadratic form in two variables $x,y$ by setting $P(x,y) = y^2 p(x/y)$.

Maybe the issue here is that **if** we're looking at the zero locus given by the rational function $X+\frac{2}{X}=0$, then this is the same as the zero locus of 
$x^2 + 2 =0$. This is not very interesting over $\mathbb{Q}$, however, if we make this polynomial homogeneous then it becomes $X^2 + 2Y^2=0$, where $[X:Y] \in \mathbb{P}^1 \mathbb{Q}$ is a point in the projective space with homogeneous coordinates. Note that the zero locus of a quadratic form is well defined, where as any other level set (i.e. $Q(X,Y) = c \neq 0$) is not.

The rationality simply means that you're taking $X,Y \in \mathbb{Q}$ and your coefficients are rational too.